# VMware Workstation Guest won't reply to external pings

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows 7 x64 machine running VMware Workstation along with a Windows XP x86 guest.

The Windows XP machine can ping every machine on my network, as expected, but none of them are able to ping the other way round. The only exception to this is that the host can ping the guest successfully.

I'm using NAT in VMware, configured as follows:

Host IP: 192.168.10.104
Host GW: 192.168.0.1

Guest IP: 192.168.60.128
Guest: GW: 192.168.60.2

Can anyone tell me how to configure my environment so that all machines can ping my guest?

Comment: Rezoan, your question is borderline unintelligible and completely off topic for ServerFault. Please review our [FAQ] for what questions are appropriate here.

Comment: choose a remote Win7 not the host -> Winbutton -> type "cmd" + Enter -> "nslookup 192.168.60.128" + Enter, write the output of the command here.

Comment: Server:  UnKnown
    Address:  192.168.10.1
    
    *** UnKnown can't find 192.168.60.128: Non-existent domain  @derty

Comment: @derty That has no bearing on anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set your XP workstation to use Bridged networking, instead of NATing through the host. Then you can treat the XP guest like any other machine on your network.

Comment: thanks Dan for your reply. i'm using wireless connection. is it possible to use Bridged networking in it??

Comment: @Rezoan Yes, it is, this works fine. Just ensure you bridge to the correct adapter

Answer (score 1):

This is quite logical as you should be bridging your network interfaces rather than using NAT. When using NAT it will use the hosts IP to do the NAT. This means no routing will be done from your host address to your VMs. When your bridge your connections you will get an ip assigned from the DHCP server on the network and you will be visible on this network (normally).

Comment: in wireless connection is it possible to to use Bridged networking??

Comment: Yea it's possible, just use the proper adapter.

Comment: Lucas kauffman, after your suggestion i have changed Network Adapter to Bridge instead of NAT. then it says the connection has Limited or no connectivity.

Comment: Did you select the correct adapter?

Comment: how can i determine it is correct adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the answers you've already gotten regarding using Bridged networking, this is a basic lesson in networking:

The guest VM is on a different network from the rest of your network. How do you get devices connected to two different devices to communicate? You route between the two networks.

Comment: i didn't understand it @joeqwerty

Comment: I'm saying that this is a good opportunity to learn a little networking, from a conceptual point of view. Q: How do you get devices connected to two different devices to communicate? A: You route between the two networks.